# Python Pandas DataReader vs get_data_yahoo which is better?

Tags: python, performance, io, pandas

I understand both of these functions do the exact same thing. Is there an advantage using one over the other?

```
from pylab import *
from pandas.io.data import *

Data=DataReader('AAPL','yahoo',start='01/01/2006')
Data2=get_data_yahoo('AAPL', start='01/01/2006')
```

Also is there any other similar functions with better or equal performance in Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code, `DataReader` is simply a wrapper around a few other functions including `get_data_yahoo`, so if you're definitely going to use Yahoo as your data source, I'd say just stick with `get_data_yahoo`. But it really doesn't matter. I don't believe there are other functions within Pandas that do this task.